# Detect compile phase in Perl

Tags: perl, runtime, compile-time

I'm working with a module that makes use of some prototypes to allow code blocks. For example:

```
sub SomeSub (&) { ... }
```

Since prototypes only work when parsed at compile time, I'd like to throw a warning or even a fatal if the module is not parsed at compile time. For example:

```
require MyModule; # Prototypes in MyModule won't be parsed correctly
```

Is there a way to detect if something is being executed at compile or run time/phase in Perl?

Comment: That is a bad idea. There are perfectly legitimate reasons to load modules at run-time - even modules that make heavy use of prototypes.

Comment: It might be a good or bad idea depending on the reasons for each case. If the whole point of a specific module is to create features that will only work if they were loaded at compile time, then there's a perfectly good reason to at least warn the user about the module being uselessly loaded at run-time.

Comment: No, it's still a bad idea. Perl doesn't just have a single compile-time / run-time. `use strict` has an entirely compile-time effect, but it's perfectly sensible for my module to do something like `sub import { require strict; require Import::Into; strict->import::into(caller) }`. My module is loading `strict` at run-time, but it's being imported into my caller's module during my caller's compile-time. That's right, my module's run time occurs *during* my caller's compile time.

Comment: Another good reason to load your module at run-time... I might not want to actually use your module, but just report its version. `require Your::Module; printf "Your::Module %s installed\n", Your::Module->VERSION;`. This might be done in, say, a setup or diagnostics script to report the installed versions of all of an application's prerequisites.

Comment: If you call `use module` in your script at compile time, everything in "module" is parsed at compile time, including what you just used as an example. Anyway, that's not related to the scenario I presented, which is making sure prototypes are properly parsed at global compile time, because after that, there's simply not way around.

Comment: "there's simply not way around"... actually, it is quite easy to bypass prototypes. `require Your::Module; &Your::Module::SomeSub(sub { ... });`. If people are using your module unusually, why not just assume that they know what they're doing? I've written plenty of [modules](http://p3rl.org/Moops) [with](http://p3rl.org/Kavorka) [compile](http://p3rl.org/Switcheroo)-[time](http://p3rl.org/PerlX::Assert) [effects](http://p3rl.org/Exporter::LexicalVars), but have never added anything like this warning to them. `require` does not do the same thing as `use`, but that doesn't ever make it useless.

Comment: By "there's simply not way around" I mean you've missed your only chance to make prototypes work. I honestly don't see how it's a bad idea to warn the user if that window has been missed and it will cause syntax errors where his code was expected to work otherwise. He will get problems with or without such warning and it might give a good hint on what went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before 5.14 (or on or after, too), you can do:

```
package Foo;
BEGIN {
    use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all';
    eval 'INIT{} 1' or die "Module must be loaded during global compilation\n";
}
```

but that (and `${^GLOBAL_PHASE}`) doesn't quite check what you want to know, which is whether the code containing the use/require statement was being compiled or run.

Comment: I tried this answer, but it didn't work. All I get is a warning (with warnings enabled, of course) when using `require` instead of `use`: `Too late to run INIT block at (eval 11) line 1.`, but it doesn't really fail and it never gets to the die call (exit code is 0).

Comment: I tried it on Perl 5.20 and on 5.12 after reading your version question. `eval` didn't fail on any of them.

Comment: Oh, that's why then. :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you're running on Perl 5.14 or higher, you can use the special `${^GLOBAL_PHASE}` variable which contains the current compiler state. Here's an example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub foo {
    if ( ${^GLOBAL_PHASE} eq 'START' ) {
        print "all's good\n";
    } else {
        print "not in compile-time!\n";
    }
}

BEGIN {
    foo();
};

foo();
```

Output:

```
all's good
not in compile-time!
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for your answer. Do you know of a way for earlier versions?

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo You can try the `INIT {}` block. It should work only, when the module is loaded in the BEGIN (e.g. with the `use`).